# How do I create a 2D array made up of a classes in java

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a minesweeper game and I want to refactor my code so that it uses a **single 2 Dimensional array** of `MineTile` **classes**.

In the MineTile class, I currently have booleans for if the mine is **visible**, one for if it has been **revealed** and one for if the player **marked it** or not.

Any tips on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

Minefield Class:

```
public class Minefield {
// Check that there are fields to hold the current state of the minefield
private boolean[][] minefield;
private int[][] minedNeighbours;


private int row;
private int col;


private int rows, columns, numMines;

/**
 * Initialize the fields, and then populate the minefield
 *
 * @param rows
 * @param columns
 * @param numMines
 */
public Minefield(int rows, int columns, int numMines) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.numMines = numMines;


    // Note that these could be rows+2, columns+2 if edge boundaries are
    // used
    minefield = new boolean[rows][columns];
    minedNeighbours = new int[rows][columns];
}

public boolean mineTile(boolean Mine, int row, int column) {

    Visible = false; 
    Flagged = false; 
    this.Mine = Mine;

    if (minefield[row][column]) {
        return false;
    } else {
        minefield[row][column] = true;
    }
    // There are a number of ways of doing this.  I've chosen to precalculate
    // the start and end points of the for loops
    // However, these checks could be internal to the for loops
    // or the arrays could have unused boundary row and columns
    int startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn;
    if (row == 0) {
        startRow = 0;
    } else {
        startRow = row - 1;
    }
    if (column == 0) {
        startColumn = 0;
    } else {
        startColumn = column - 1;
    }
    if (row == this.rows - 1) {
        endRow = row;
    } else {
        endRow = row + 1;
    }
    if (column == this.columns - 1) {
        endColumn = column;
    } else {
        endColumn = column + 1;
    }
    for (int i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
        for (int j = startColumn; j <= endColumn; j++) {

            minedNeighbours[i][j]++;

        }
    }
    return true;
}

public int getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public int getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

/**
 * Provide the grid representation
 *
 * @return Stars for mines, ints for adjacent
 */
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (minefield[i][j]) {
                s += "*";
            } else {
                s += minedNeighbours[i][j];
            }
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    return s;
}

/**
 * A simple loop creating random coordinates, mining the tile until the
 * required number of mines have been laid
 */
public void populate() {
    int created = 0;
    while (created < this.numMines) {
        int row = (int) (Math.random() * this.rows);
        int col = (int) (Math.random() * this.columns);
        if (!minefield[row][col] && !(row == 0 && col == 0)) {
            mineTile(row, col);
            created++;
        }

    }
}
```

MineTile Class:

```
public class MineTile {

    private boolean Mine;
private int row;
private int col;
private boolean Visible;
private boolean Flagged;

    public MineTile(boolean Mine, int row, int col){
        this.Mine = Mine;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        Visible = false;
        Flagged = false;
    }

}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: To create the array, MineTile[][] tiles = new MineTile[rows][cols]; This creates an array filled with nulls. You then need to create each of the tiles, probably in for loops.

Comment: @Pshemo, I did edit it. This time I deleted and put it in again. I hope it sticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the constructor for the class `MineTile`  you posted:

```
public MineTile(boolean Mine, int row, int col){
    this.Mine = Mine;
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
    Visible = false;
    Flagged = false;
}
```

You can define a 2d array with a double loop like the example below:

```
MineTile[][] tiles = new MineTile[rows][columns];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
        tiles[i][j] = new MineTile(false, i, j);
    }
}
```

This is a simple basic example you can adapt to your needs, with different values for initializations of the 2d array elements.

Comment: Would I define it in the Minefield class or MineTile class?